# MS-DOS, save COM data to file and display on console at the same time

Tags: dos

I have a MS-DOS 3.22 machine that will receive simple text data over serial COM1.

I can make it save to file by doing `TYPE COM1 >> data.log` and I can make it show the data on the console with `TYPE COM1 >> CON` but I can't do this simultaneously as the `TYPE COM1` is a never ending command.

Is there a way for me to both display the COM data on my console and to save it to file simultaneously?

thx!

Comment: You might want to try retrocomputing.SE

Comment: Thanks!
I did not know that this existed, will do!

Comment: On Retrocomputing: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8078/278